# [Angular7][Jest] How to test a MergeMap?

Tags: angular, testing, rxjs, jestjs, angular7

I need your help :)

I used angular 7 and Rxjs. For the test, I used Jest.

I have my component that use a MergeMap between 2 httpClient like that :

```
addPost() {
  this.postService.createPost(post).pipe(
    mergeMap( (response) => { return this.postService.getPost(response.headers.get('Location'));} )
  ).subscribe(
    (post) => {
      this.content =""; this.postService.addingPostToArray(post);
    }, (error) => {
      //todo
    }
  );
}
```

And my PostService :

```
createPost(post:Post) {
 return this.httpClient
   .post('http://localhost:8080/posts', {post: post}, {observe:  'response'}); 
}

getPost(url: any) {
   return this.httpClient.get<Post>(url);
}
```

And I created test to my component like that :

```
it('should test addPost OK', () => {
postService = TestBed.get(PostService);
spyOn(postService, 'createPost').and.returnValue(of('test'));
spyOn(postService, 'getPost').and.returnValue(of('test'));

component.addPost();

expect(postService.createPost).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(postService.getPost).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

});

But the problem is that my getPost is never called.

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected spy to have been called, but it was not called.

  131 |
  132 |     expect(postService.createPost).toHaveBeenCalled();
> 133 |     expect(postService.getPost).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

How can I test the mergeMap ?

I hope that my explanations isn't too weird :)

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string test is not going to have the property response.headers.get('Location').

Try

```
spyOn(postService, 'createPost').and.returnValue(of({ headers: { get: _ => 'test' } }));
```